# How to get ERRORLEVEL for each command in FOR LOOP?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, errorlevel

I am comparing a list of files from 2 folders using a windows batch file. It prints the results whether PASS/FAIL.

**Current Working Batch File:**

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in (list.txt) do compare Folder1\%%f.png Folder2\%%f.png
```

If there are 3 files, the output after running this command would look like this:

```
PASS
FAIL
PASS
```

If I echo the %ERRORLEVEL% here, it would return 0 because the for loop ran fine.

```
echo %ERRORLEVEL%

0
```

**My Requirement**

Echo the result of each command in the FOR loop instead.

**My Expected Output**

```
0
1
0
```

How do I change the batch file to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that FAIL changes the `ERRORLEVEL`, Use `&` to echo `ERRORLEVEL` for each command:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in (list.txt) do compare Folder1\%%f.png Folder2\%%f.png & echo !ERRORLEVEL!
ENDLOCAL
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
PASS
0
FAIL
1
PASS
0
```

I assume PASS/FAIL is the output of your `compare` utility. To hide this output use redirection `>` to `NUL` like this:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in (list.txt) do compare Folder1\%%f.png Folder2\%%f.png > NUL & echo !ERRORLEVEL!
ENDLOCAL
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0
1
0
```

From [documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true):

> & : command1 & command2
>
> Use to separate multiple commands on one command line. Cmd.exe runs
>   the first command, and then the second command.

Comment: This cannot work, because: 1. you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for `!ErrorLevel!` to get the ErrorLevel of the iteration; otherwise, the ErrorLevel present when reading the entire command line is returned; 2. [`&&`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) prevents non-zero ErrorLevels to be returned, you must use `&` instead;

Comment: @aschipfl, sorry for overlooking. I have updated the answer and added documentation as well. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I tried this. Getting the below output:  
PASS  
!ERRORLEVEL!  
FAIL  
!ERRORLEVEL!  
PASS  
!ERRORLEVEL!

Comment: @InsecureNoob, then you forgot to enable delayed expansion obviously...